# how to update only one function from use effect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-effect

i have two functions inside use effect,
i want that the first function invoke only once, and the second invoke every render if state of "meetingArray" change

```
useEffect(() => {
    getWeekMeetings();
     meetingArray();
}, []);
```

how can i handle this?

Comment: You should divide the function two useEffect parts and then call the array meetingArray part.

Answer (score 6):

You can have more than 1 useEffect function

```
   // called once
  useEffect(() => {
    getWeekMeetings();
  }, []);

  // called when meetingArray State changes
  useEffect(() => {
    meetingArray();
  }, [meetingArray])
```